# What is the difference between hex bytes output using different types of encoding schemes in C#?

Tags: c#, encoding

Consider the following C# code

```
     int x = 126;
     string s = "126";
     FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.txt", FileMode.Create);
     StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
     sw.WriteLine(x);
     sw.WriteLine(s);
```

The output(in Hex bytes stored in test.txt) is 31 32 36 0D 0A 31 32 36 0D 0A

If I make changes to Line 4:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.Unicode);
```

The output is: FF FE 31 00 32 00 36 00 0D 00 0A 00 31 00 32 00 36 00 0D 00 0A 00

Could someone help me with the logic. Is there any reference regarding  different encoding schemes and their behavior with File systems using C#

Comment: If you are interested why `int` and `string` are encoded to same hex, `StreamWriter` writes as string. Try `BinaryWriter` to see difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that you read [Joel Spolsky's excellent article on the subject of character sets and encodings](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). In short:

- A file is just a sequence of bytes.
- A string is a sequence of characters.
- A *character set* defines a collection of characters and assignes a unique *code point* (an integer that represents the character - note that "integer" is not necessarily an `int`) to each character.
- When you want to store a string in a file, you need to convert the character sequence into a byte sequence. For character sets with 256 characters or less, there is usually a one-to-one correspondence between characters and bytes, but for bigger character sets, such as Unicode, it gets more complicated.
- An *encoding* defines how the code points for the characters of the string should be translated into bytes.

Therefore, when you change the encoding, the same string gets translated into a different sequence of bytes.

Note that the behavior of character sets and encodings is independent of the programming language. What does change is how you refer to and use the various encodings and character sets (usually, an encoding is tied to a particular character set, so selecting an encoding will also implicitly select the character set). In C#'s case, `Encoding.Unicode` is poorly named - it's the Unicode *character set*, but the UTF-16LE *encoding* (in which every second byte will be `00` if you only use English characters).

Also, note that strings are represented as `char` arrays internally in the program, where each `char` is a value that represents two subsequent bytes from a UTF-16 encoding (so some fancy characters might actually be represented as two `char` values). You can't access that array directly, and most of the string functionality tries to abstract away this fact. This internal encoding doesn't affect how strings get written to files (either, you select an encoding manually, or you get the default character set of the operation you're invoking - which for `StreamWriter` is UTF-8 (thanks to @xanatos for the correction)).

Comment: Absolutely perfect... there is even the difference between the character set and the encoding of the character set (unicode and utf-X)... only one thing: *an integer that represents the character* it would be better to use the word *number*, because integer is too much similar to `int`

Comment: @xanatos: Thanks! This is the question that made me hit 20,000 reputation points, so I put some extra effort into it ;-) I think "number" is too generic, but I added an explanation that I do not mean `int`.

Comment: `StreamWriter` by default uses UTF8, so *or you get the default character set of the operating system* is false at least compared to the question. There is even a small imprecision: you use twice `UTF-16`, but Encoding.Unicode is `UTF16-LE` (as written [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx)), while C#/.NET encoding is probably UTF16 (current platform) (for example the XBox360 is Big Endian)

Comment: @xanatos: Thanks; I've been doing too much Java lately... I also reworded the description of the internal string representation.